# A car moves in a straight line with velocity $t^{−2}−1/25 ft/s$.

Tags: definite-integrals

For the total displacement, I keep getting $7/150$ but it seems to be incorrect!
As for the total distance, I split the integrals to $[3,5]$ and $[5,6]$. I added the integrals together and took the absolute value and I still get $7/150$. Can anyone help me with this question? I've done a lot of these questions but for some reason, I can't seem to get this particular question correct. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Don't write the whole question to the title, especially if it includes formulas. Write the formulas with MathJax to the question body. Then show your own work and what you have tried.

Comment: What's the complete problem on earth?

Comment: the car will change move direction at t = 5, you have to split the whole process into two part. Also, note the direction of first parts of movement  are opposite to the 2nd part. That is, S = s1 - s2 when using scalar calculation

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int_3^5 \left(\frac{1}{t^2} - \frac{1}{25} \right)\,dt + \left|\int_5^6 \left(\frac{1}{t^2} - \frac{1}{25} \right)\,dt \right| = \frac{3}{150}
$$
and
$$
\int_3^6 \left(\frac{1}{t^2} - \frac{1}{25} \right)\,dt= \frac{7}{150}
$$
Does this help?